# Change element color based on codition HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, angularjs

I am trying to change the color backround of an element based on a condition.
For example if number >2, color green.
My css:

```
 .color-green {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
   }

<h9>My number{{ data.number}}</h9>
```

I tried with ng-class but does not work. What am I missing here?

```
<td ng-class = "{'color-green':data.number>=2}"> <h9>My number {{ data.number}} </h9></td>
```

Or what would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: is it because of an extra space I see here 'color-green '?

Comment: seems that is not the reason

Comment: you changes do look correct, can you inspect in the browser, if you class is getting applied on the element and if your defined class is accessible?

Comment: also can you confirm the version? are you using angular-js?

Comment: #mak15 My class was not beeing applied. can you please post this as an aswer so I can accept?

Comment: sure, will do that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your changes do look correct, can you inspect in the browser to see if your class is getting applied on the element and if your defined class is accessible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `ng-class` with `[ngClass]` :

```
<td [ngClass]= "{'color-green':data.number>=2}"> <h9>My number {{ data.number}} </h9></td>
```

Reason: `ng-class` was used in angularJS. `[ngClass]` is used in Angular 2+.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like in Angular [Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass):

```
<td [ngClass]="data?.number >= 2 ? 'css-class-one' : 'css-class-two'"></td>
```

Also, use the optional chaining operator to prevent run time undefined issue on your number property. Do it with this **?** marke like this `data?.number`